# UIImageView doesnt display assigned image inside it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I want to store some `UIImages` in a singleton class. I have done it like this

**Inside my singleton.h class**

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImage *img1;
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImage *img2;
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImage *img3;
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImage *img4;
```

**In my .m class**

```
@synthesize img1,imgCover,img2,img3,img4;

+ (MyProductClass *)sharedManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedService == nil) {
        sharedService = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedService;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // initialize stuff here
        imgCover=[[UIImage alloc] init];
        img1=[[UIImage alloc] init];
        img2=[[UIImage alloc] init];
        img3=[[UIImage alloc] init];
        img4=[[UIImage alloc] init];   
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then my 1st viewcontroller im storing image in `Singleton class` like this. `myproductObj`singleton class object

```
UIImage *imgSelected=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
myproductObj.img1=imgSelected;
```

Then Im retrieving the image in anotherviewcontroller (Actually this is the previous Viewcontroller to the storing viewcontroller )

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([appstatusClass.strIsImageselected isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
        int count=[appstatusClass.strnumberofImageSelected intValue];
        scrollViewImage.pagingEnabled=YES;
        [scrollViewImage setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollViewImage.bounds.size.width*count, scrollViewImage.bounds.size.height)];
    }
    if (count==1) {
        scrollViewImage.scrollEnabled=YES;
        imageAddphoto.image=myproduct.img1;
    }
}
```

This is my log cat when I check these

```
(lldb) po myproduct.imgCover
<UIImage: 0x15ea4000>

(lldb) po imageAddphoto.image
<UIImage: 0x15ea4000>
```

But my `imageAddphoto` image view is blank. It doesn't display any image. If I set a image like `imageAddphoto.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Car.png"]` then it displays. But why can't my singleton image display?

Comment: AppDelegate *appdelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; imageView.image=[uiimage imagenamed:appdelegate.img1]

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `imgSelected` is not blank too?

Comment: Your singleton isn't working because you went about using it wrong. I added an answer detailing how you should.

Answer (score 0):

As have created a img1 object in your singleton class it is showing you the address of that object when you are printing.

you are not storing the image in singleton class it will return no image.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a singleton class, you're going to have to make a few modifications.

In `MyProductClass.m` (This is what you mean by Singleton.m, right?)

```
// Be sure to declare a static representation of sharedService
static MyProductClass *sharedService;
@implementation
```

Now when you actually set values to your singleton, it should be done similar to the following:

```
[[MyProductClass sharedService] setImg1: imgSelected];
```

Accessing values of your singleton class should be done with something like:

```
[[MyProductClass sharedService] img1];
```

Also, I would make a few changes to `MyProductClass.m`. These changes are detailed below.

```
// In your singleton class, the class method sharedManager should share the same value as your static variable `sharedService`. Further, you should actually set sharedService a little differently than you do.
+ (MyProductClass *)sharedManager {
@synchronized(self) {
if (sharedService == nil) {
    sharedService = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
}
return sharedService;
}
```

Should be:

```
+ (MyProductClass *)sharedService {
    if (!sharedService) {
    sharedService = [[MyProductClass alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedService;
}
```

Lastly, if you elect to use `allocWithZone:` (it's not necessary in order for singletons to work), be sure to override the method. Doing something like this should be sufficient:

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    if (!sharedService) {
        sharedService = [super allocWithZone:zone];
        return sharedService;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```